# Why is there no fused multiply-add for general-purpose registers on x86_64 CPUs?

Tags: x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, amd-processor

On Intel and AMD x86_64 processors, SIMD vectorized registers have specific fused-multiply-add capabilities, but general-purpose (scalar, integer) registers [don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add) - you basically need to multiply, then add (unless you can fit things into an `lea`).

Why is that? I mean, is it that useless so as to not be worth the overhead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Integer multiply is common, but not one of the *most* common things to do with integers.  But with floating point numbers, multiplying and adding is used all the time, and FMA provides *major* speedups for lots of ALU-bound FP code.

Also, floating point actually avoids precision loss with an FMA (the `x*y` internal temporary isn't rounded off at all before adding).  This is why [the ISO C99 / C++ `fma()` math library function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fma) exists, and why it's slow to implement without hardware FMA support.

Integer FMA (or multiply-accumulate, aka MAC) doesn't have any precision benefit vs. separate multiply and add.

---

Some non-x86 ISAs do provide integer FMA.  It's not useless, but Intel and AMD both haven't bothered to include it [until AVX512-IFMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_IFMA) (and that's still only for SIMD, basically exposing the 52-bit mantissa multiplier circuits needed for double-precision FMA/`vmulpd` for use by integer instructions).

Non-x86 examples include:

- [MIPS32](https://github.com/MIPT-ILab/mipt-mips/wiki/MIPS-Instruction-Set#multiplicationdivision), `madd` / `maddu` (unsigned) to multiply-accumulate into the `hi` / `lo` registers (the special registers used as a destination by regular multiply and divide instructions).
- [ARM `smlal`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDJJHFC.html) and friends (32x32=>64 bit MAC, or 16x16=>32 bit), also available for unsigned integer.  Operands are regular R0..R15 general purpose registers.

---

**An integer register FMA would be useful on x86, but uops that have 3 integer inputs are rare**.  CMOV and ADC have 3 inputs, but one of those is flags.  Even then, they didn't decode to a single uop on Intel until Broadwell, after 3-input uop support was added for FP FMA in Haswell.

Haswell and later can track fused-domain uops with 3 integer inputs, though, [for (some) micro-fused instructions with indexed addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes).  Sandybridge/Ivybridge un-laminate instructions like `add eax, [rdx+rcx]`.  (But Nehalem could keep them micro-fused, like Haswell; SnB simplified the fused-domain uop format).  Anyway, that's fused domain, not in the scheduler.  Only Broadwell/Skylake can track 3-input integer uops in the scheduler, and that's only for 2 integer + flags, not 3 integer registers.

Intel does use a "unified" scheduler, where FP and integer ops use the same scheduler, and it can track proper 3-input FP FMA.  So IDK if there's a technical obstacle.  If not, IDK why Intel didn't include integer FMA as part of BMI2 or something, which added stuff [like `mulx`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MULX) (2-input 2-output `mul` with mostly explicit operands, unlike legacy `mul` that uses `rdx:rax`.)

---

**SSE2/SSSE3 *does* have integer mul-add instructions for vector registers**, but only horizontal add after widening 16x16 => 32-bit ([SSE2 `pmaddwd`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PMADDWD)) or (unsigned)8x(signed)8=>16-bit ([SSSE3 `pmaddubsw`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PMADDUBSW)).

But those are only 2-input instructions, so even though there's a multiply and an add, it's very different from FMA.

---

Footnote:  The question title originally said there was no FMA "for scalars".  There is scalar FP FMA with the same FMA3 extension that added the packed versions of these:  [`VFMADD231SD`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VFMADD132SD_VFMADD213SD_VFMADD231SD) and friends operate on scalar double-precision, and the same flavours of vfmaddXXXss are available for scalar float in XMM registers.

Comment: I would think FMA would be useful for array-of-struct accesses, for example `struct foo x[1024]; … y = x[z].bar;`. Is this not the case?

Comment: @xxpor: You'd need to have the struct size in a register for that, unless you had integer MAC (multiply-accumulate) instructions that took an immediate operand for the multiplier.  And given x86 addressing modes, you just need to scale `z` by the struct size (with one `imul` or shift), then `[x + scaled_z + offset]` is a valid addressing mode where `x` and `scaled_z` are registers.  e.g. `imul esi, 24` / `mov eax, [rdi + rax + 12]`.  (Or `lea esi, [rsi + rsi*2]` / `mov eax, [rdi + rsi*8 + 12]` to do the multiply by 24 as `*3` with a cheap LEA and `*8` as part of the addressing mode.)

Comment: RE: "ARM smlal": as I see in the ARM DDI 0487E.a there is `FMADD`, etc. (Table C3-70 Floating-point multiply-add instructions).

Comment: Re: "Non-x86 examples" consider adding "TriCore: MADDxxx instructions" (e.g. `MADD.F`).

Comment: @pmor: `madd.f` is a floating-point FMA. This question (and that bullet-list of non-x86 examples) is about integer MACs (on general-purpose integer registers).  The [TriCore manual google found](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/tc1_6__architecture_vol1.pdf?fileId=db3a3043372d5cc801373b0f374d5d67) mentions a *16x16-bit multiply-accumulate unit (with optional saturation)* in the feature list which sounds like an example of what I'm looking for, but searching on "accumulate" doesn't find the definition, and I didn't try other search strings.

Comment: Re: "about integer MACs": OK. I have no experience with integer MACs.